# $A$ is an upper triangular matrix with $k$ nonzero main diagonal entries. $\mathop \Rightarrow \limits^? $ $ rank A\ge k$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let  $A\in M_n$  is an upper triangular matrix with $k$ nonzero main diagonal
entries.

Is this true that, $ rank A\ge k$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes: the span of the columns corresponding to the $k$ nonzero diagonal entries is $k$-dimensional, so the span of all the columns has dimension $\ge k$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It is easy to see this by noting that the number of zeros on the diagonal is the *algebraic* multiplicity of the eigenvalue zero, and the nullity (dimension of the kernel) is the *geometric* multiplicity of the same. With the rank-nullity theorem, the conclusion follows.

Answer (score 2):

by scalar multiplication and subtraction of columns the matrix may be transformed to one of the same rank and nullity whose action admits the decomposition
$$
I_k \oplus N_{n-k}
$$
where $N_{n-k}$ is a nilpotent operator on an $n-k$-dimensional subspace $V$ and $I_k$ is the identity on $V^{\perp}$